# How to verify whether list A contains all elements of list B?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to determine whether a list `A` contains all the elements in the list `B` (including duplicate elements).

For example, for `A = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3}; B = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3}` should return `False`.

For `A = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3}; B = {1, 1, 1, 3}` should return `True`.

For `A = {3, 3, 1, 1, 1}; B = {1, 1, 1, 3}` should return `True`.

For `A = {3, 3, 1, 1, 4}; B = {1, 1, 4, 4}` should return `False`.

What can I do to solve this problem succinctly?

```
SubsetQ[{3, 3, 1, 1, 4}, {1, 1, 4, 4}] (*the result is True, which does not meet the requirements*)
```

In addition, I'd like to know what other ways to get the index of an array:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
RandomSample[Array[x, 10]]
% /. _[x_] :> x(*Besides this method, I would like to know as many methods as possible*)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["MultisetInclusionQ"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultisetInclusionQ):

```
ResourceFunction["MultisetInclusionQ"][{1,1,1,3,3},{1,1,1,3,3,3}]
ResourceFunction["MultisetInclusionQ"][{1,1,1,3,3},{1,1,1,3}]
ResourceFunction["MultisetInclusionQ"][{3,3,1,1,1},{1,1,1,3}]
ResourceFunction["MultisetInclusionQ"][{3,3,1,1,4},{1,1,4,4}]
```

> False

> True

> True

> False

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = And @@ NonNegative[Subtract @@ (KeyUnion@(Counts /@ {##}) /. _Missing -> 0)] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
A1 = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3}; B1 = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3};
A2 = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3}; B2 = {1, 1, 1, 3};
A3 = {3, 3, 1, 1, 1}; B3 = {1, 1, 1, 3};
A4 = {3, 3, 1, 1, 4}; B4 = {1, 1, 4, 4};

f @@@ {{A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, {A3, B3}, {A4, B4}}
```

> ```
> {False, True, True, False}
> ```

You can also use [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) + [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = Fold[DeleteCases[#, #2, 1, 1] &, #2, #] === {} &;

f2 @@@ {{A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, {A3, B3}, {A4, B4}}
```

> ```
>  {False, True, True, False}
> ```

For the second part of the question:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
rs = RandomSample[Array[x, 10]]
```

> ```
> {x[1], x[7], x[5], x[6], x[9], x[3], x[10], x[4], x[8], x[2]}
> ```

```
rs[[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {1, 7, 5, 6, 9, 3, 10, 4, 8, 2}
> ```

```
First /@ rs
```

> ```
> {1, 7, 5, 6, 9, 3, 10, 4, 8, 2}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
test =
  {{{1, 1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3}},
   {{1, 1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 3}},
   {{3, 3, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 3}},
   {{3, 3, 1, 1, 4}, {1, 1, 4, 4}}};
```

Define `InclusionQ`

```
InclusionQ[{a_, b_}] /; Complement[a, b] =!= {} := False

InclusionQ[{a_, b_}] :=
 And @@ GreaterEqual @@@ Transpose @ Map[Tally @* Sort, {a, b}][[All, All, 2]]
```

Apply it

```
InclusionQ /@ test
```

{False, True, True, False}

Answer (score 2):

```
test = {{{1, 1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3}}, {{1, 1, 1, 3, 3},
        {1, 1, 1, 3}}, {{3, 3, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 3}}, 
        {{3, 3, 1, 1, 4}, {1, 1, 4, 4}}};
```

---

Using `DeleteElements` to define `InclusionQ`:

```
InclusionQ[a_, b_] := DeleteElements[b, Values@# -> Keys@# &@Counts[a]] === {}

InclusionQ[#1, #2] & @@@ test

(*{False, True, True, False}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ContainsAll[MapIndexed[#1[#2]&,Sort[#1]],
  MapIndexed[#1[#2]&,Sort[#2]]]&@@@{{A1,B1},{A2,B2},{A3,B3},{A4,B4}}

(* {False,True,True,False} *)
```

```
A1 = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3}; B1 = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3};
A2 = {1, 1, 1, 3, 3}; B2 = {1, 1, 1, 3};
A3 = {3, 3, 1, 1, 1}; B3 = {1, 1, 1, 3};
A4 = {3, 3, 1, 1, 4}; B4 = {1, 1, 4, 4};
```